# How to return C pointer automatically

Tags: c++

I am currently wrapping a library written for C for my C++ program. As to do so I make objects that automatically take care of deleting the C parts when an object goes out of scope. I have done this as an example for an `sqlite3_stmt *`:

```
class auto_stmt_t
{
public:
    auto_stmt_t() :
        stmt_(NULL)
    {

    }

    virtual ~auto_stmt_t()
    {
        reset();
    }

    void reset()
    {
        if (stmt_ != NULL)
        {
            ::sqlite3_finalize(stmt_);
            stmt_ = NULL;
        }
    }

    bool prepare(const std::string &query, sqlite3 *db)
    {
        reset();
        return ::sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, query.c_str(), -1, &stmt_, NULL) == SQLITE_OK;
    }

private:
    sqlite3_stmt stmt_;

};
```

Now I want to pass this object to a `sqlite` function such as `sqlit3_step` which takes a `sqlite3_stmt *` as argument.

Is there a way I can just pass my object which then will get auto castet? Something like this:

```
auto_stmt_t stmt;
stmt.prepare("SELECT bar FROM foo");
::sqlite3_step(stmt);
```

I have seen that this is possible, which operator will I need to overload to automatically get the `sqlite3_stmt *` for this to work?

Comment: You mean a conversion/casting operator?

Comment: exaclty thats what I mean

Comment: Yes, this is what I am looking for :)

Comment: I will, stack overflow makes me wait 15 Minutes ;)

Comment: Why not just use `std::unique_ptr`?

Comment: can it have custom destructor functions? I need to free it with `sqlite3_finalize`

Comment: Yes of course. Read the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr). see how `unique_ptr` manages a `FILE*`

Comment: read it... not really fits my need, thanks though for the suggestion, will come in handy for other problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add

```
operator sqlite3_stmt* () const { return &stmt_; }
```

to your wrapper class.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to add a wrapper member function that calls `sqlite3_step` for you and also checks for errors.

Comment: I have wrapped the database function in another class

Comment: @Nidhoegger Than that class should be able to extract `sqlite3_stmt` from your statement class. Make the database class a friend or add an extractor function.

Comment: yes, it should be able to... using this operator... why use another method? And I dont use friend classes, i dont like it and in most cases consider it bad practice.

Comment: @Nidhoegger With that implicit conversion operation you get poor ownership -  the user of the class may inadvertently get the statement handle and close it.

Comment: not if the `auto_stmt_t` class definition is private within the database class and only used within this class as convenience wrapper...